# Object is successfully passed as props but individual properties are 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-props

so I am passing an object from my App component to a child component.
Within the render method I am able to see the value of my object by using console.log as so

`this.props.data.documents[0]`

I am able to see the key value pairs of the object contained at documents[0],
but when I try to single out the individual properties (like below) I get an undefined error.

`this.props.data.documents[0].username`

This is what console.log(this.props.data.documents[0]) prints

`{user_id: "5dfd9f8afc5bdf1bef11b78c", username: "christine", name: "second", src: "../images/5dfd9f8afc5bdf1bef11b78c_second.png"}
user_id: "5dfd9f8afc5bdf1bef11b78c"
username: "christine"
name: "second"
src: "../images/5dfd9f8afc5bdf1bef11b78c_second.png"`

And here is the error for console.log(this.props.data.documents[0].src

`react-dom.development.js:25206 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined`

Why could this be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. Could you include what the console shows when you log `this.props.data.documents[0]` for reference?

Comment: I am getting an Uncaught TypeError alert. I've updated the original post with the error message as well as some more info on the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Documents is an array of data. Try check for each object inside the array and see if every object were supplied with the property 'src'. You can do this by looping the documents array, and check the value of src. If its what i expect, then the looping should be a mixed messages of src value and undefined, hence your root cause. I encountered this many times, and mostly it was due to objects inconsistency inside collection. Collection should be consistent across all objects, supplied with same amount of properties even if the value for certain property is null.